# PHP code being displayed in clear text?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian, google-cloud-platform

Setting up my first ever server from scratch for a migrated Wordpress site. It's been a long journey, but I'm almost at the end of this.

This is what I've done so far.

- Created the GCP micro instance.
- This tutorial on how to setup the LAMP stack. - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-debian
- Followed a tutorial on how to setup virtual hosts - granted I'm still just trying to get the primary domain setup. (Can't post the link due to reputation level on ServerFault)
- Migrated my Wordpress database into the new instance.
- Edited my config files with the updates (I'm 99.9% wordpress is configured correctly now after having gone through many tutorials and troubleshooting).

When I hit the website - what I get instead is just clear text of the wordpress code to the site. This is strange also because my /wp-admin/ part of the site seems to be initializing the PHP.

I've managed to open up the apache log files and I find this fatal error that I believe is causing the problem:

> [Wed Jun 07 16:50:45.835692 2017] [:error] [pid 22258] [client
>   181.199.83.55:49298] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'OO_Api' not found in /var/www/argineconsul.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/online-outbox-subscription-form/includes/controller.php
>   on line 7

Is the reason PHP failing is because of this one plugin? Or is the PHP not rendering for another reason?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! My server is at: http://35.188.216.56/ .

Comment: Please edit your question with how you've set up your server, configuration files, etc.

Comment: Sadly, your edit doesn't help. If you want a good answer you need to ask a good question. The best that we can tell you with the information you provided is: well, you messed something up. Fix it. If you want something more detailed, you'll need to do the work of writing a good question.

Comment: @EEAA ah, any thoughts on where I can look for more information? Right now I can't seem to get past this page.

Comment: Tell us what you've done so far, what your configuration files are, etc.

Comment: @EEAA OK - I've stepped through everything I've done so far. Any specific configuration files you can suggest I include?

Comment: @EEAA I found an error log. I think this is the problem.

Comment: Something like `sudo a2enmod php5 && sudo apache2ctl restart` should do it... not sure what the php module is called and whether you did php5 or 7 and ...

Comment: @ivanivan this command returned "Module php5 already enabled" and nothing else. The server is still rendering in clear text.

Comment: Fatal error in a Wordpress plugin will indeed cause a site to render a blank page.

Comment: @AlexD seems you are correct. I removed the offending plugin, and now I have an entirely new problem... ;-) Resolving out this question for now! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @AlexD ah no green checkbox next to comments - do you want to post that as an answer and I'll hit the green check box?

Comment: @alexforyou thanks, you can try to upvote a comment, as it is impossible to post an answer due to the question being on hold.

Answer (score 1):

Fatal error in a Wordpress plugin will indeed cause a site to render a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Check your apache configuration (`.htaccess`) for the line that looks like:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Alter that line to be sure that `index.php` is the first item

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Comment: It's not related to the Apache configuration because of these sentences  "When I hit the website - what I get instead is just clear text of the wordpress code to the site. This is strange also because my /wp-admin/ part of the site seems to be initializing the PHP." Also, true reason of this issue was discussed at the comments section.